# AWK. Pass number of records in a file to a variable

Tags: awk

I have the following script which calculates the sum of a particular column. i am now trying to also get the number of records. however any combination i try, it gives me a syntax error. I am trying to get the number of records passed to a variable tr below.

```
BEGIN { FS="\t" }
{ sum[FILENAME] += $42 }
{tr=NR}
END {
    for (i=1;i<ARGC;i++)
        printf "%s %15d\n", ARGV[i],sum[ARGV[i]],tr>> "output.abc"
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use NR in the END block?

Comment: @sidoh Hi. I tried it like this in the printf statement but it doesn't return the value. Could you pls advise how i shud write it.

'code' printf "%s %15d\n", ARGV[i],sum[ARGV[i]],NR>> "output.abc" 'code'

Comment: Read the syntax error and THINK about what it says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format in `printf` expects two arguments and you give it three, you want:

```
printf "%s %15d %d\n",ARGV[i],sum[ARGV[i]],tr
```

Comment: +1. I had look up `%i` as I've never seen it before and according to the gawk manual it's equivalent to`%d` so - why use both `%d` and `%i` in one statement?

Comment: @EdMorton good point, answered quickly & was just just thinking `i` for integer, changed for consistency.